# azure cache on localhost

Tags: c#, caching, azure

I'm developing an application to run in azure.
I'm making use of the azure cache, however when I run this locally I don't want to connect up to Azure to use the cache because it's a bit slow and tedious.

Can you run the cache locally?

[EDIT]
This is .Net C#

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you do need to connect to azure to test the windows azure cache service. Read this for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg278342.aspx

Comment: To be clear - in order to have full fidelity with the Azure caching service, currently, your only option is to test against the caching service.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Windows Server AppFabric Cache when local debug. It utilizes very similar configuration and program mode, which means almost all you need to change is the cache server IP and access token.

But I'd better to create a separated Cache layer to isolate the cache operations. For example introduces ICache interface with Add, Get, Remove, etc. methods. Then you can implement the Azure Cache, Memcached, In-Proc Cache, etc. in vary cases.

There's a good cache layer you might be interested in, check the ServiceStack project at GitHUB https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/CacheAccess

Comment: I cannot get AppFabric Cache to install because the Azure SDK is installed. Hence, no service is already listening for a reference to localhost to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. To use the windows azure caching service locally, you'll always have to route your request to azure, which adds a serious delay on top of the request.

To property test your cache, you need to deploy your service in azure.

As others said, you can use Windows Server AppFabric caching locally, but be warned, there are some differences between the Windows Server AppFabric caching and the Windows Azure caching service, like for example the notifcation based invalidation on local cache items is not supported in azure. Make sure not to use any of these features while developing locally, or you might get surprised when deploying your service to the cloud.

Only the timeout based invalidation on local cache is supported for the windows azure caching service. Windows azure caching service is designed to be used for your cloud services, so it makes sense it's kinda crappy when using with on on-premise application.

Answer (score 1):

Azure AppFabric caching uses a subset of the functionality of [Windows Server AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849) caching.  If you're willing to setup a server in house with the cache installed you could probably get something comparable to using the Azure cache.  I haven't tried this myself, so while I know that the code you'd need to write is more or less the same between the two, I'm not sure how different the configs need to be.

Chances are though that it's going to be a lot less time and effort to just use the Azure cache.

Answer (score 1):

This article specifically talks about what you are trying to do.  Create a caching "infrastructure" that switches between local and distributed cache based on configuration(s):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708748.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use azure in-role cache and try locally using emulator